# Order of CSS filter styles affects background image on mobiles only

Tags: html, css, css-filters

I've created an example [here](http://www.cssdesk.com/CN5T2). It's supposed to show a grayscale image. The color image is converted to grayscale by the CSS filters. This works on my desktop (safari and chrome browsers), but does not work on my phone (safari and chrome browsers) - the image appears in color. However, if I swap the order of the bottom two lines of CSS, to give this:

```
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

then the image magically appears in grayscale on both my phone and desktop. Why is the order important on my phone, but not my desktop?

Full code -

HTML:

```
<div class="gray" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zDPDlNd.jpg)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
.gray {
background-size:cover;background-position:center center;position:relative;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: gray;
filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

Comment: Try using `filter : saturate(0)` instead.

Comment: Since the [filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) is still experimental and not widely supported, this issue is likely differences in how different browser versions interpret and render the output.

Comment: Filter is widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter In fact, the svg filter is supported in all browsers listed on that site.